# Binding Json Arrays to model Web Api

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have such struct of classes. The problem is when I transfer to web api controller User  json serialized before, List of actionees count is 0.
Serialized Json looks like that:

```
{"$id":"1","UserId":1,"RealName":"vas`ka","PasswordHash":"password",
 "Email":"somemail","Actionees":
   {"$id":"2","$values": 
      [{"$id":"3","ActioneeId":1,"Status":"doing", "CloseDate":null,
        "DeletedFlag":false, "CreationDate":"2013-03-11T11:48:24.08", 
        "Users":null,  "Comments":null}, {"$id":"4","ActioneeId":2,"Status":"doing",  
        "CloseDate":null, "DeletedFlag":false, 
        "CreationDate":"2013-03-11T12:46:08.787", "Users":null,"Comments":null}
      ]
   }
}


public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }
     public String Email { get; set; }
    public String RealName { get; set; }
    public String PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Actionee> Actionees { get; set; }
}

public class Actionee
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 ActioneeId { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean DeletedFlag { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Actionee> Comments { get; set; } 
}
```

I added this strings into application_start:

```
        var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
        var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(User), null, int.MaxValue, false,  true, null);
        xml.SetSerializer<User>(dcs);

        var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;   

       And I tried to deserialized in this way: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization
```

Comment: you are using json.net?

Comment: no. I tried to do this with newtonsoft in WebApi, but it serialize just ok, but when i try to bind, there are no list of Actionees.

Comment: Could you add a bit of your serialization and deserialization code please

Comment: Okay could you edit your question by adding this code (serialization and deserialization methods) I can test it

Comment: last question : the string result is a result from a serialization of entity framework object?

Comment: yes, I tested directly with entity framework models.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not well formatted,because of entity framework object serialization

you have extra properties like

> "$id":"2","$values"

JsonFormatter can't recognize tis extra properties and can't desrialize your object
you need to convert your  entity framework object into your user object 
in your web api controller

Comment: It means that I must use models unsted entity framework entities, And my models may have same structure?

Comment: yes , another alternative is to use the "code first" approach of entity framework http://www.strathweb.com/2012/03/serializing-entity-framework-objects-to-json-in-asp-net-web-api/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and

Comment: it doesnt solve the format of my result json, when I copy data to Models.

Comment: I solve this problem with media type formatters. Like in msdn example. Thank you for helping me. But i`m caring about always copying data from entities to model. Is it a right way?

Comment: try to deserialize it with your entity framework object instead of your User object